# Where can I find a good example of C# /// xml documentation comments in use?

Tags: c#, documentation

I'm looking for some good examples of .NET XML-style source code comments and all the various tags available in use.  Where can I find some good examples?

Comment: I found this blog post by Scott Hanselman quite useful: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/EffectiveXMLDocumentWithCNDocLutzsDocumentorAndTheMicrosoftHTMLHelpWorkshop.aspx

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[Here's](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ast78ax.aspx) a list of the recommended tags in Visual Studio, and [here's](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/bb330936.aspx) a list of C# samples - many of which should have XML docs in them.  One of the examples in the C# download is "XMLDoc" - and the readme from that starts with the following...

> XML Documentation Sample
>
> This sample shows how to use XML to
>   document code.