# How do I document mathematical computations inside my code

Tags: c#, documentation

I am documenting a large application that does a lot of mathematical computations. The computation itself is very simple but it is a lot. My question: Is there a way to document these calculations efficiently?
Here is an example (Note: there are hundreds of lines of operations like this):

```
double printJobTime = (zHeight / (surfaceDensity / 1000)) * buildTime;
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/xmldoc/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where can I find a good example of C# /// xml documentation comments in use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1228552/where-can-i-find-a-good-example-of-c-sharp-xml-documentation-comments-in-use)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest use *XML comment* as follow:

```
/// <summary>
/// [Explaine the method function...]
/// </summary>
/// <param name="..."></param>
/// <param name="..."></param>
/// <returns>[Explaine the result...]</returns>
public ... [YourMethod]()
{
    ...
}
```

Take a look at the following link:

[How to: Insert XML comments for documentation generation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/generate-xml-documentation-comments?view=vs-2019)

By enabling the **XML Documentation file:** (in the project properties)

[image]

The *XML Documentation file* will generate automatically when build the project.

Comment: For this you need to refactor the code and extract the mathematical computations into their own methodes and document these methodes.